# Get next day selected hour epoch

Tags: java, android

If the user selects 01:25 AM, how to get the corresponding epoch time for this hour for the next day?

I did something like that, which is pretty "face coded" :

```
private long returnEpochForThisHour(String hour){
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
    Date date = new Date();
    String stringDate = dateFormat.format(date).substring(0, 10) + " " + hour;
    Date newDate = new Date(stringDate);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(newDate);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    Date lastDate = c.getTime();
    System.out.println(lastDate.getTime());
    return lastDate.getTime();
}
```

When doing something like:

```
returnEpochForThisTime("01:25");
```

It returns:

```
1544491500000
```

But in Android devices it's not working properly. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by "in Android devices it's not working properly"?

Comment: I'm sure that there is a better way to do this. And when i'm testing, it gives non valid epoch times.